Filtering column customer ID that has multiple product ID in SQL
I have a data like below:



cust_id
acc_id
prd_id




cust_a
id_a1
prdA


cust_a
id_a2
prdA


cust_a
id_a3
prdB


cust_a
id_a4
prdC


cust_b
id_b1
prdA


cust_c
id_c1
prdA


cust_d
id_d1
prdB


cust_d
id_d2
prdC


cust_e
id_e1
prdC


cust_f
id_f1
prdA


cust_f
id_f2
prdB


cust_g
id_g1
prdB


cust_g
id_g2
prdB



From the table we can see that cust_a,cust_d and cust_f have multiple product. However cust_a and cust_g has one product with different acct_id while the other only have one product and one acct_id.
My objective is to have only customer that have multiple product. Expected table is as below:



cust_id
prd_id




cust_a
prdA


cust_a
prdB


cust_a
prdC


cust_d
prdB


cust_d
prdC


cust_f
prdA


cust_f
prdB



This is my code, and I think there might be simpler way to do it or any amendment to my code.
select cust_id, prd_id
from acct_tbl
where exists (select cust_id, count (*)
              from acct_tbl 
              where prd_id is in ('prdA','prdB','prdC')
              group by cust_id
              having count (*) >=1)

where prd_id is in ('prdA','prdB','prdC');


You could express this as:
SELECT cust_id, prd_id
FROM acct_tbl
WHERE cust_id IN (
    SELECT cust_id
    FROM acct_tbl
    GROUP BY cust_id
    HAVING MIN(prd_id) <> MAX(prd_id)
)
ORDER BY cust_id, prd_id;

Another way, using window functions:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*,
        MIN(prd_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS min_prd_id,
        MAX(prd_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS max_prd_id
    FROM acct_tbl t
)

SELECT cust_id, prd_id
FROM cte
WHERE min_prd_id <> max_prd_id
ORDER BY cust_id, prd_id;


If your platform supports COUNT(DISTINCT..., then:
select distinct cust_id, product_id
from acct_tbl a
where (select count(distinct product_id) 
       from acct_tbl b
       where b.cust_id=a.cust_id) > 1

